Is 1h20 of transfer in PEK enough? Same terminal, no luggage, booked with reseller
EDIT: The flight and transfer went very well. The transfer time was indeed short because China makes you undergo security scanning, biometry check (passport and photography) even if you are in a transfer and don't go out of the airport. I had little time but I didn't miss the connection.

I booked a flight through a reseller (Kiwi.com) for CDG-BKK through PEK, off-season (November).
I plan on having no luggage. The transfer time in PEK is 1h20.
I checked online and it seems like the two terminals are the same: I fly Air China and they only use Terminal 3. I am of French nationality.
It will be my first time setting foot in China so I expect to have to go through a complete check for fingerprints, photos, etc.
I read about transfer time online, and the opinions differ wildly (from "at least 4 hours are needed!" to "50 minutes are more than enough!").
I also read the following regarding Chinese airports and security:

Domestic to domestic: no control
International to domestic: security + immigration
International to international : security

I am quite conflicted, and frankly a bit stressed in advance, and I would like to know:

Is 1h20 enough to go from one plane to another on the same terminal?
Is there a specific route to follow in the airport?
What controls should I expect?
I believe passport + plane ticket should be enough (no visa, no additional documentation). Is this right?


You might not be allowed to board the first flight without a valid visa

I think not. On the French diplomacy website (https://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/fr/conseils-aux-voyageurs/conseils-par-pays-destination/chine/#entree), I read the following: 1.2 Transit
Du 1er décembre 2023 au 30 novembre 2024, les titulaires de passeports ordinaires français se rendant en Chine pour un transit sont exemptés de visa pour une durée maximale de 15 jours. Translation: From December 1, 2023 to November 30, 2024, holders of ordinary French passports traveling to China for transit are exempt from visa requirements for a maximum period of 15 days.

This assumes that your airline believes you will count as "in transit" despite you appearing to them to finish your journey in China.

There's one important thing you haven't told us: is this booked as a single ticket (which would make this trivial), or is it a self-transfer (which would make it somewhere between very risky and outright impossible)? Kiwi are infamous for pushing self-transfers, but they do sell regular connections, and since both flights are on Air China, it is more likely than not that it's a "real" connection, not a self-transfer.

@CMaster While I believe this is a real connection and thus a real transit (and the point is thus moot), french citizens are now visa-exempt even for actual entry into China (for a maximum of 15 days).

@jcaron Good remark, thanks. How can I know if it is a real connection? Here is a screenshot of the informations on my flight: https://imgur.com/gnnqNNc

Are the PNR and e-ticket numbers the same on both flights?

@jcaron Yes! they are the same

Real connection it is, then. If you use the Air China website's "Check My Booking" feature with your PNR and last name you should also be able to see both flights on the booking.

@C.Crt.  That's why you should always buy with the airline directly and not with a reseller, especially not KIWI. It may be a few dollars cheaper but it comes with a lot more risk especially it something doesn't go as planned (changes, cancellation, missed connection, etc.). In  this case you got lucky (so far) but booking with the airline is always much safer.

@Hilmar I know and I messed up. But in my defense, the price difference was insane (544€ vs 768€). I know it's a bad idea but it's terribly hard to resist.

It all depends on whether this is a "real" connection (both flights on a single ticket) or a self-transfer (flights booked separately, even if you bought them at the same time).
Kiwi are infamous for pushing a lot of the latter, but they also sell "real" connecting flights, and given that the two flights are with Air China and the short connection time, I would think this is your case here.
For a real connection, since this is international-to-international, you shouldn't even need to go through immigration at all (though I'm not familiar with procedures in China, so I may be wrong). It's probably just a matter of deplane-transit security-go to gate, for which 1h20 should be plenty. There's a minimum connection time (MCT) for different types of connections taking into account the parameters of each airport, and airlines just won't sell connecting flights under that MCT. In short: if they sell it, they believe you can actually do it.
If you don't make it, they will have to rebook you on the next available flight, possibly pay for meals or a hotel if you have to wait long/overnight, and you may even be eligible for compensation (unless extraordinary circumstances etc.). So that gives them quite a bit of incentive to make sure you make it.
On the other hand, if this actually a self-transfer, I'd say just forget about it. While you could actually make it (given you have no checked luggage, and provided you can actually check-in online/on your mobile), but the risk is too great if there's a delay.

"Kiwi are infamous for pushing a lot of the latter" - I have seen that even with the same airline.

@André many LCCs don’t do connections, only point-to-point, so it’s indeed quite common for them to sell two tickets on the same airline in those circumstances. Probably happens for traditional airlines as well but it’s certainly less likely. But they’re not completely mad either (I hope) and I don’t think they would sell a self-transfer with 1h20 between the flights.

Thank you for the answer. Coming back much later, my transfer went very well although I jogged to the gate to be sure.
